# How to use in a Vue.js child component a third component which was lazy loaded in a parent component?

Tags: vue.js, lazy-loading, vue-router

I have loaded a `UserList` component in a parent component, how can I use it in a child component without having to reload it ? (and prevent from going again and again through the `created` hook)

The parent component looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-link to="/users">Users</router-link>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  components: {
    UserList: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "user-list" */ "./UserList.vue")
  }
}
</script>
```

And my child component `Users.vue` looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <user-list />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
  },
  mounted () {
    console.log('Users component mounted.')
  }
}
</script>
```

I get the following error message in javascript console:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the
>   component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
>   the "name" option.

Comment: any time you have an element in a template, like `<user-list />`, an instance will get created. So the premise of this question is a bit off. Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve? is it to have code splitting working with individual components, or do you actually want to use a component that only gets runs the `created` hook once?

Comment: @Daniel I need a component that only gets run the `created` hook once.

Comment: then you'll need to put the logic somewhere else so you can have multiple instances of that component, or you will need to mount the component further up the tree, so it only gets added once.